# Not able to update object properties with AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, promise

Trying to solve problem were my object has old snapshot of itself and refuses to update itself when I replace it with new data using AJAX.

```
var user, status;

function getData(){                
    var userData = getUserData(),
        orderStatus = getOrderStatus(),
        allDone = $.when(userData, orderStatus);         
    allDone.then(function(data, data2){                                        
        status = parseInt(data2[0]);  
        user = JSON.parse(data[0]);        
        console.log("User", user);                           
    });    
}

function getUserData() {
    return $.ajax({
        type: "POST",        
        url: functionsPath,        
        data: {
            action: 'getUserData'
        }
    });
}

function getOrderStatus() {
    return $.ajax({
        type: "POST",        
        url: functionsPath,
        data: {
            action: 'getOrderStatus'
        }
    })
}

//onclick event
function verify(){
   console.log(user);
}
```

Here is screenshot of the problem: This first one is from console. I call this inside getData() function. Take a closer look into user.content.page4

[image: Image 1]

Next image is taken from network tab. As you can see data is different when it not. There are "symbols" with values. Why are these two different?

[image: Image 2]

This is problem when I try to call `user` within verify() since it has the old snapshot of itself and doesn't return my symbols etc. It really feels like a console bug. Symbols are listed in database.

**EDIT**

I think I got more closer to the problem. Result loses its "Symbol-1", "Symbol-2" and so on immediately when I parse it. **So when I parse user.content page4 loses Symbol properties.**

Before parsing I have it, but soon as I parse it I lose every symbol properties and their values.

Comment: you need to call `verify` once `allDone.then(function(data, data2){ ...` has completed ... it's not exactly obvious how those two functions `getData` and `verify` are "sequenced" by your code - since the code you posted calls neither of them

Comment: can you try `console.log(JSON.stringify(user, null, 4));` - that way you get a true snapshot of the user object (because the console lies)

Comment: @JaromandaX Let's say its an onclick event. I don't want it to happen on allDone. It is kind of "check" that I do.

Comment: @JaromandaX I will try this one sec.

Comment: also try the same console.log just after you assign it - I suspect some code you haven't shown may be changing the `user` object (has to be something, right)

Comment: @JaromandaX No this is the only code that changes the user object.

Comment: can't be ... objects do not change by themselves

Comment: @JaromandaX Well tell me about it. Each time I getData() I set user object.

Comment: does `changePage` do anything with `user`

Comment: @JaromandaX No, let me remove it so it doesn't raise questions.